# org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist on new Object

Tags: java, hibernate

I know there are many of these threads, but nothing of their solutions would work for me.

```
public void process(EreignisTexteSpezifikationEingang spezifikationEingang) throws BusinessException {

        String eingangBaureiheBauart = spezifikationEingang.getBaureiheBauart();
        String eingangSoftwareVersion = spezifikationEingang.getSoftwareVersion();
        boolean eingangIsDeault = spezifikationEingang.getIsDefault();
        AnlageStatus anlageStatus = spezifikationEingang.getAnlageStatus();

        Assert.argNotNull(spezifikationEingang, "EreignisTexteSpezifikationEingang");
        Assert.argNotNull(eingangBaureiheBauart, "BaureiheBauart");
        Assert.argNotNull(eingangSoftwareVersion, "Software Version");
        Assert.argNotNull(spezifikationEingang.getInputStream(), "texteInputStream");

        checkExistDefaultVersionForBR(eingangBaureiheBauart, eingangIsDeault);

        EreignisSpezifikation newSpez = new EreignisSpezifikation();
        newSpez.setAnlageDatum(new Date());
    newSpez.setSoftwareVersion(eingangSoftwareVersion);
    newSpez.setIsDefault(eingangIsDeault);
    newSpez.setBemerkung(spezifikationEingang.getBemerkung());

    if (AnlageStatus.UNDEFINED.equals(anlageStatus) || null == anlageStatus) {
        newSpez.setStatus(AnlageStatus.VERFUEGBAR);
    } else {
        newSpez.setStatus(anlageStatus);
    }

    BaureiheBauart baureiheBauart = bauartDao.findByName(eingangBaureiheBauart);
    newSpez.setBaureiheBauart(baureiheBauart);
    if (baureiheBauart == null) {
        throw InvalidEreignisSpezifikationException.invalidBaureihe(eingangBaureiheBauart, spezifikationEingang
                .getFilename());
    }

    EreignisTexteParser parser = parserFactory.getEreignistexteParser();

    List<Ereignistext> texte = parser.parse(spezifikationEingang.getInputStream());

    newSpez.setEreignistexte(texte);

        ereignisSpezifikationDao.makePersistent(newSpez);
```

EreignisSpezifikation:

```
    ...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PK_EREIGNIS_SPEZ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "EreignisSpezSequence", sequenceName = "SEQ_EREIGNIS_SPEZIFIKATION", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EreignisSpezSequence")
    private Long id;

    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_EREIGNIS_SPEZ", nullable = false)
    List<Ereignistext> ereignistexte;
```

The Last index of the sequence is 189 which is NOT set.

I've already tried to change the CascadeType to Merge but changes nothing.

This Object is definitely not in the database still it fails. Any ideas?

Stack:

```
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:141)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:762)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:755)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.engine.spi.EJB3CascadingAction$1.cascade(EJB3CascadingAction.java:53)
 at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:396)
 at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:339)
 at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:207)
 at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:426)
 at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:366)
 at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:342)
 at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:207)
 at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:164)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:449)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:772)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:746)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:750)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:875)
 at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:563)
 at de.db.udg.diagnose.udgdiag.dao.GenericDAOJpa.makePersistent(GenericDAOJpa.java:44)
    ...
```

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace and the part between  `EreignisSpezifikation newSpez = new EreignisSpezifikation();` and `ereignisSpezifikationDao.makePersistent(newSpez);`

Comment: @Jens hope it helps

Comment: the Content of `texte` must be stored before `newSpez` will be stored

Comment: it is? @Jens or you mean on database?

Comment: i mean stored in database

Comment: @Jens how do I check that?

Comment: It seems `newSpez.setBaureiheBauart(baureiheBauart);` creating a problem. I believe that's loaded from DB and maybe already in the persistent context. Hence instead of using `persist`, can you try `merge` or `saveOrUpdate`.

Comment: Is the list of `Ereignistext` persistent?

Comment: @ujulu it seems like it isn't, but I dont know yet how to fix it.

Comment: You can check if the parsed instances have a persistent identity.

Answer (score 0):

The exception clearly says:

> detached entity passed to persist on new Object

Your problem is that you are setting some properties that you take from `spezifikationEingang` object to your `newSpez` object, For hibernate these objects are not persisted because they haven't been loaded in the current session context.

For example in the following lines:

```
List<Ereignistext> texte = parser.parse(spezifikationEingang.getInputStream());

newSpez.setEreignistexte(texte);
```

You are trying to set `texte` to your `newSpez` object, while it is a non persisted `List`, because you have just created it from `parser.parse()` call.

Comment: How do you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @0x45 Because you are passing the `spezifikationEingang` to the method, and it may be out of the `context` of the session inside the method, so it needs to be persisted.

Comment: You can confirm it by a debug and get the line tht throw the Exception.

Comment: `ereignisSpezifikationDao.makePersistent(newSpez);` throws it

Comment: Yes I know, but what's the exact `entity` that throws it, try to comment/uncomment, the `set....` lines and check?!

Comment: The Entity is `EreignisSpezifikation`

Comment: Yes I know, I meant whta's the exact property try to comment, `newSpez.setStatus(anlageStatus);
` and check it, it should work.

Comment: Commenting this one out makes it work `newSpec.setEreignistext()` but why?

Comment: Because `texte` is a new created list with `parser.parse()` call, and it haven't been already persisted.

Comment: Dumb question: How do I persist it? @chsdk

Comment: You can either `load`it inside the method or use `.merge()` method to persist it.

Comment: `javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Multiple representations of the same entity` with merge